# exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: books is not mapped [FROM books...

Tags: mysql, hibernate, mapping, classcastexception

**I'm trying to make CRUD+spring app which create/remove/update books. And everything work fine, but searching a book from the DB. Please help.**

```
@Controller
public class BookController {
...................
    @RequestMapping("searchBook")
    public ModelAndView searchBook(@RequestParam("searchBook") String title){
        List<Book> booksList = bookService.getAllBooks(title);
        return new ModelAndView("booksearch", "booksList", booksList);
    }
}
```

**There's a books.jsp:**
    ...................
        
    
    Back to main menu

### Search books by title:

ID
                Title
                Author
                Description
                ISBN
                Print Year
                Read Already
                Edit
                Delete
            
            
            
            
                
                    ${book.id}
                    ${book.bookTitle}
                    ${book.bookAuthor}
                    ${book.description}
                    ${book.isbn}
                    ${book.printYear}
                    ${book.readAlready}
                    ">Edit
                    ">Delete
                
            
            
        
    
    **There's a structure of my project: http://clip2net.com/s/3ON3F6n

```
There's a getAllBooks() method from BookDaoimpl:**

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Book> getAllBooks(String bookName) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE BOOK_TITLE like '%" + 
bookName + "%'";
        List<Object[]> bookObjects = session.createQuery(query).list();
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        for (Object[] bookObject : bookObjects) {
            Book book = new Book();
            int id = (int) bookObject[0];
            String title = (String) bookObject[1];
            String description = (String) bookObject[2];
            String author = (String) bookObject[3];
            int isbn = (int) bookObject[4];
            int printYear = (int) bookObject[5];
            int readAlready = (int) bookObject[6];
            book.setId(id);
            book.setBookTitle(title);
            book.setDescription(description);
            book.setBookAuthor(author);
            book.setIsbn(isbn);
            book.setPrintYear(printYear);
            book.setReadAlready(readAlready);
            books.add(book);
        }
        System.out.println(books);

        return books;
    }
```

**There's a MySQL DB:http://clip2net.com/s/3ON4e7o and THIS http://clip2net.com/s/3OPyIHL**

```
My Book.class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "BOOK_TITLE")
    private String bookTitle;

    @Column(name = "BOOK_AUTHOR")
    private String bookAuthor;

    @Column(name = "BOOK_DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "ISBN")
    private int isbn;

    @Column(name = "PRINTYEAR")
    private int printYear;

    @Column(name = "READALREADY")
    private int readAlready;
......................................


**My mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:**
<!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service, DAO -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.maxim.bookmanager" />

    <!-- View Resolver -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- DataBase Information -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookmanager" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate & SessionFactory Bean definition-->
    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>ru.maxim.bookmanager.model.Book</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- BookDao & BookSession beans -->
    <bean id="bookDao" class="ru.maxim.bookmanager.dao.BookDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="bookService" class="ru.maxim.bookmanager.service.BookServiceImpl">
        <property name="bookDao" ref="bookDao"></property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.maxim.bookmanager" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Transaction -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

If I change query to something like "SELECT Book FROM Book b", I receive a new exception: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: ru.maxim.bookmanager.model.Book cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

What is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: After a debugging I understood that my list: List<Object[]> bookObjects = session.createQuery(query).list(); - full of data if my query is "SELECT b FROM Book b"; and in foreach my app craches on a line for (Object[] bookObject : bookObjects) {. If I change foreach with iterator my app crashes on:
 while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next()
Something wrong with object...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing the wrong way to get the data from database.

you have two options to resolve that error : -

- **Using Sql**

  ```
  Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  String query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE BOOK_TITLE like '%" + bookName + "%'";  
  List<Object[]> bookObjects = session.createSQLQuery(query).list();
  List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(); 
  //rest code snippet  will be same as your code snippet .
  ```
- **Using Native Hql**

  ```
  String book_title="book title name";
  org.hibernate.Query que=session.createQuery("from Book where bookTitle  like ?");
  que.setString(0,"%"+book_title+"%");
  //rest will be same as your code snippet
  ```

  here in Native HQL instead of table name (BOOK_TITLE) entity name is used(BOOK) and in place column name (BOOK_TITLE) class variable name(bookTitle) will be used